# How do I set a static IP address for a disconnected interface?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, network-interface, tcp-ip

I am setting up an Arch/[Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro_Linux)-based machine that only occasionally will be connected to network. I.e. most of the time its Ethernet card is disconnected.

I run into this curious problem - when I try to use networking commands the interface is down (I sit next to it with my laptop that has a Wi-Fi Internet connection). So I am not sure if it is working properly.

- How do I set up the network without an Ethernet connection present so that when I finally plug in a cable I can be sure that the address will be 192.168.1.1?

I found the **answer**: use `SkipNoCarrier=yes` in the `netctl` profile. It is in [Manjaro StaticIP](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Setup_Static_IP) wiki and in Arch [netctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl) page.

Comment: on a side note, you can configure network interface to get a DHCP address, but have the server always send you same IP. check with your modem (if at home) or network admin. on a side side note home modem are likely to give you same IP if you connect on a regular basis.

Comment: In my setting network admins are very remote and unavailable. My machine will be standalone data collector (surveys) and I will periodically connect to it via crossover cable to siphon off new data.

Comment: well then If have nothing to add to @maunlinglaws's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this for example:

> For a static IP configuration copy the
>   `/etc/netctl/examples/ethernet-static` example profile to `/etc/netctl`
>   and modify Interface, Address, Gateway and DNS) as needed.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> /etc/netctl/my_static_profile
>
> Interface=enp1s0
> Connection=ethernet
> IP=static
> Address=('10.1.10.2/24')
> Gateway=('10.1.10.1')
> DNS=('10.1.10.1')
> ```

Link to the official Arch Wiki **[here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netctl#Wired)**.

This of course only works if you **don't** use Network Manager or something similar to control your network.

Comment: Thanks, this is where it gets also confusing. Am I understanding right that `netctl` is the most basic method? This is what I want. But I think `nm` was installed by default; perhaps I need to uninstall it? If I understand correctly nm is useful mainly for managing wifi connections, but for basic server it is not needed. How do I select which method is in charge of the nic?

Comment: Network Manager is **not** installed by default on Arch. I don't know if it is in Manjaro however, it's been quite a while since I used that distro. Personally, I always use `netctl` in Arch.

Comment: I think it is. As I want simplicity and basics there, I probably should remove `networkmanager` or else I do not know if it is interfering or not?

Comment: @r0berts `netctl` isn't the most basic method. As stated in the wiki page, it uses profiles to manage network connections. Those profiles are started/stopped by `systemd` services. See [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Configure_the_IP_address) for a more general idea. To manage WiFi connections you can use `wifi-menu`, which works with netctl. You can just disable the `NetworkManager.service`.

Comment: I found the parameter to ensure address is always on even if cable not connected - you have to put `SkipNoCarrier=yes` in the profile.